# Add an item at bottom in listview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I'm making an app similar to `to-do's app` and i can able to add an item from `textfield` to `listview.builder`. In this whenever i add a new item it comes below of the todo's list in `listview.builder`. Now the problem is i make `reverse: true` inside `listview.builder` and if i add an item this time it is coming at the top instead at bottom. How can i display the new item at bottom even if it is `reverse: true` inside `listview.builder`.

Comment: Can you show an example or your code pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works, if this is what you wants

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<TodoItem> items = [
    TodoItem('first name', ' first body'),
    TodoItem('second name', ' second body'),
    TodoItem('third name', ' third body'),
    TodoItem('fourh name', ' fourh body'),
  ];

  int newCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
            //items.add(TodoItem('${newCount.toString()} new ', ' added ${newCount.toString()} '));
            items.insert(0, TodoItem('${newCount.toString()} new ', ' added ${newCount.toString()} '));
            newCount++;
            setState(() {});
          }),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(items[index].name),
                  subtitle: Text(items[index].body),
                );
              }))),
    );
  }
}

class TodoItem {
  final String name;
  final String body;

  TodoItem(this.name, this.body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a boolean (for reverse) stored in your state, you could then, when adding the item, add it either to the front or the back depending on this value

```dart
// State variables
bool isReverse;
List<Todo> todos;

void addListItem(Todo item) {
  if (isReverse) {
    // add to the front of the original array
    todos.insert(0, item);
  } else {
    // add to the back (default case)
    todos.add(item);
  }
}
```

Though I'd intuitively say that when the list is reversed, you expect new items to end up at the top.

### Order example

To illustrate this insertion at index 0 and reverse, I've put the following code and ran it on https://dartpad.dev/

```dart
void main() {
  List<String> todos = [];
  
  todos.addAll(['Clean Bedroom', 'Do dishes', 'Cook food']);
  
  print('Normal order: $todos');
  print('Reversed order: ${todos.reversed.toList()}');
  
  // Add item at index 0 (start of the normal list, end of the reversed list)
  todos.insert(0, 'Buy Groceries');
  
  print('Normal order with groceries: $todos');
  print('Reversed order with groceries: ${todos.reversed.toList()}');
}
```

The output of which is

```
Normal order: [Clean Bedroom, Do dishes, Cook food]
Reversed order: [Cook food, Do dishes, Clean Bedroom]
Normal order with groceries: [Buy Groceries, Clean Bedroom, Do dishes, Cook food]
Reversed order with groceries: [Cook food, Do dishes, Clean Bedroom, Buy Groceries]
```

Comment: Still doesn't work (means it is coming at the top if i use todos.insert(0, item).

Comment: i am using `reverse:true` inside `listview.builder` widget.

Comment: here the index 0 is opposite because of `reverse: true`.

Comment: When reversed, you want the new item to still be added to the bottom. In other words, you want to add it to the top of the original array, at index 0. Reversed will then place it at the top, it should work... Did you call `setState` to update the list, so it rebuilds with the new item added?

Comment: When reversed, i want the new item to be added at bottom.
And yes i'm calling setState

Comment: I'm really not sure what the problem is. When reversed, an item at index 0 will appear at the bottom. See also my code snippet that I added at the bottom of my answer.